# Spring Boot elasticsearch produce warnings: Transport response handler not found of id

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I setuped a web app with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch`. Everything work well - I can populate indexes with my stand alone Elasticsearch 5. But I continue to receive some weird warnings:

```
2018-05-08 03:07:57.940  WARN 32053 --- [ient_boss][T#7]] o.e.transport.TransportService           : Transport response handler not found of id [5]
2018-05-08 03:08:02.949  WARN 32053 --- [ient_boss][T#8]] o.e.transport.TransportService           : Transport response handler not found of id [7]
2018-05-08 03:08:07.958  WARN 32053 --- [ient_boss][T#1]] o.e.transport.TransportService           : Transport response handler not found of id [9]
2018-05-08 03:08:12.970  WARN 32053 --- [ient_boss][T#2]] o.e.transport.TransportService           : Transport response handler not found of id [11]
...
```

Simple app to reproduce:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

  @Configuration
  @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.test")
  public class EsConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String esHost;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int esPort;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
    private String esClusterName;

    @Bean
    public TransportClient client() throws Exception {
      Settings esSettings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", esClusterName).build();
      InetSocketTransportAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketTransportAddress(
          InetAddress.getByName(esHost), esPort);
      return new PreBuiltTransportClient(esSettings).addTransportAddress(socketAddress);
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate(Client client) throws Exception {
      return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }

}
```

My compose file for ES

```
version: "2.3"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.8
    ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms700m -Xmx700m
      - PATH_LOGS="/tmp/el-log"
      - cluster.name=dou
    cpu_shares: 1024
    mem_limit: 1024MB
```

As a project transitive dependency I have `org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.6.8`. Looks like versions of ES instance & library are the same.

So, what does this warning mean & how should we deal with it?

Comment: With every request, you get these log messages or only to a few? and is your code complete for me to reproduce the issue?